# How to initialize a 2d Vector with different sizes for the row and the column in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I don't know why I can't find a clear cut answer to this, as in Java this is straight forward and easy. I am writing a function where the inputs are two different strings and I am creating a double array (or in C++ a vector) where I define the size of the rows and columns.

In Java, this is easy, all you have to do is:

```
int myFunction(String text1, String text2) {

  int[][] arr = new int[text1.size() + 1][text2.size() + 1];

  ...

}
```

But in C++, I am having a hard time doing that with a 2D vector. I did this:

```
int myFunction(string text1, string text2) {

 vector<vector<int>> arr(text1.size() + 1, text2.size() + 1);

 ...

}
```

I know since I am not supposed to pass that in the second parameter for the vector initialization, I just don't know what to do. I get this error:

> Line 5: Char 29: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
> 'vector<vector>'
> vector<vector> temp(text1.size() + 1, text2.size() + 1);

Can someone explain how to initialize a 2D vector with defined sizes in C++ please ? Thanks !

Comment: Thank you Retired Ninja ! I will try to mark it as solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of the [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) constructor is the initial value of the elements in the vector.

Here you are looking fo the rows, so `vector<int>(text2.size() + 1)`:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(text1.size() + 1, vector<int>(text2.size() + 1));
```

---

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why you `using namespace std;` is considered bad practise.